# Descendants and content model in HTML specification

Tags: html, w3c, specifications

Let us say we have this markup:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

- The *li* is a child and descendant of *ul*
- The *span* is a child and descendant of *li*
- The *span* is descendant of *ul*

Reading the [specifications for ul](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element) we have:

> **Content model**:
>             Zero or more li and script-supporting elements.

And the semantics section for *Content model* say, *(emphasize mine)*:

> ***Content model***
>              A normative description of what content must be included as
>              children ***and descendants*** of the element.

I am surely thinking of this wrong, but I can not get the two to compute. As a *span* is not part of *"Zero or more li elements"* and it is a descendant of the *ul*.

If the spec said: *"A normative description of what content must be included as children of the element."* I would get it, but that might crash with other parts of the specification.

My question is how to interpret this.

---

To add some more context. An *ul* can only have *li* as children. But from the above, if one forget everything one know about HTML etc., I would have interpret that as one of two:

- It must have zero or more *li* elements, but can also have anything else, or
- It can *only* have *li* elements both as children and descendants.

By *"zero or more"* the latter stands stronger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quoted description, from 3.2.3 Element definitions, is rather loose and even misleading. The next part, 3.2.4 Content models, describes what the content model really is: “Each element defined in this specification has a content model: a description of the element's expected contents. An HTML element must have contents that match the requirements described in the element's content model. The contents of an element are its children in the DOM, except for template elements, where the children are those in the template contents”.

Thus, the content model specifies both the allowed and the required content (though not all elements have required content), in terms of children, which means *child nodes*. This includes, as applicable, element childen and text node children (e.g., some elements have only text allowed as content).

This means that an a `ul` element may only have `li` and `script` elements as children. The `li` elements have content models of their own, which are rather permissive. There is no required content; even `<ul></ul>` is allowed in HTML5.

Comment: Thanks. Then I'm not missing something of it's meaning from a semantic  point of view I guess. Have read the other sections as well, but the phrase/quote mentioned has kept bugging me. Perhaps somewhat extra because it is linked directly trough out the specification. As such I look at it as a *Term description*: *short, concise, can be vague but not misleading.*